# Dropbox last modification with Java API

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am writing a Dropbox console application. I need to find last modification for my account. I can get file metadata with date of last modification, like this:

```
DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren(path);
for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
    System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());

}
```

But how can I find the latest modification for all of my folders?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API and the [official Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) don't expose a modified time for folders, but we'll consider it a feature request.

For files, you can access [`clientModified`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#clientModified) and [`serverModified`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#serverModified) on [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html).

(Note that the code in your question uses the old, deprecated Java SDK, so you should switch to the [new one](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java).)